# understanding async/await using Dapper Repositories in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm using Dapper Repositories to access to the Data Base in my ASP.Net Core project and I had an unexpected result while testing some functionalities, so I decided to ask about how the asynchronous process works.

First, I made a function where some rows are inserted and updated in the same table:

### First function: Insert/Update in the same table

```
...
using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
  try
  {
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    if (insertList.Count > 0) // if there are insert items, insert then in A table
    {
      asks.Add( AItemRepository.BulkInsertAsync(insertList, trans ) );
    }

    if (editList.Count > 0) // if there are update items, update them in A table
    {
      asks.Add( AItemRepository.BulkUpdateAsync(editList, trans ) );
    }

    // wait for the tasks to finish
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    trans .Commit();
    conn.Close();    
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  ...
```

BulkInsertAsync and BulkUpdateAsync are functions from the Dapper Repositories and look like this:

```
public virtual async Task<int> BulkInsertAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> instances, IDbTransaction transaction = null)
    {
        var queryResult = SqlGenerator.GetBulkInsert(instances);
        var count = await WriteConnection.ExecuteAsync(queryResult.GetSql(), queryResult.Param, transaction);
        return count;
    }
public async Task<bool> BulkUpdateAsync(IEnumerable<TEntity> instances, IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        var queryResult = SqlGenerator.GetBulkUpdate(instances);
        var result = await WriteConnection.ExecuteAsync(queryResult.GetSql(), queryResult.Param, transaction) > 0;
        return result;
    }
```

They just create the sql query based on the entity(the db table) and execute the query with ExecuteAsync(...).
This first function works well, it inserts and updates using transaction. 
The thing is that I call both BulkInsertAsync() and BulkUpdateAsync() and await after that, so I guess both connections are executed concurrently and the process waits for them to finish the Task here:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

After that I made another function where I had to insert new rows into two different tables:

### Second function: insert in different tables

```
...
using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
  try
  {
    SqlQuery sql;

    Task<int> ATask = null;
    if (AItemList.Count > 0) // if there are A items, insert in A table
    {
      sql = AItemRepository.SqlGenerator.GetBulkInsert(AItemList);
      ATask = conn.ExecuteAsync(sql.GetSql(), sql.Param, trans);
    }

    Task<int> BTask = null;
    if (BItemList.Count > 0) // if there are B items, insert in B table
    {
      sql = BItemRepository.SqlGenerator.GetBulkInsert(BItemList);
      BTask = conn.ExecuteAsync(sql.GetSql(), sql.Param, trans);
    }

    // wait for the insert tasks
    if (ATask != null) await ATask;
    if (BTask != null) await BTask;

    trans .Commit();
    conn.Close();    
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    ...
```

Seems almost the same as the first function, right? But it throws the next exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot set MySqlCommand.CommandText when there is an open DataReader for this command; it must be closed first

This exception doesn't happen when I debug the function using breaking points in both ExecuteAsync(), I guess because the first ExecuteAsync() has enough time to close the Reader and when the second ExecuteAsync() is called the Reader is already closed. So I realized that its not possible to call executeAsync almost simultaneously, and changed the source to:

```
...
using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
{
  try
  {
    SqlQuery sql;

    Task<int> ATask = null;
    if (AItemList.Count > 0) // if there are A items, insert in A table
    {
      sql = AItemRepository.SqlGenerator.GetBulkInsert(AItemList);
      await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql.GetSql(), sql.Param, trans); // wait to finish
    }

    Task<int> BTask = null;
    if (BItemList.Count > 0) // if there are B items, insert in B table
    {                
      sql = BItemRepository.SqlGenerator.GetBulkInsert(BItemList);
      await conn.ExecuteAsync(sql.GetSql(), sql.Param, trans); // wait to finish
    }

    trans.Commit();
    conn.Close();    
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  ...
```

### My conclusion

So if I'm not wrong, you can't call two ExecuteAsync() without waiting them to finish, so does it mean that the first function actually does not call BulkInsertAsync() and BulkUpdateAsync() without waiting, and the second one is executed when the previous is finished? In that case, would it be better to change the calls to the code below?

```
Task<int> insertTask = null;
if (insertList.Count > 0) // if there are insert items, insert then in A table
{
  await AItemRepository.BulkInsertAsync(insertList, trans );
}
Task<bool> updateTask = null;
if (editList.Count > 0) // if there are update items, update them in A table
{
  await AItemRepository.BulkUpdateAsync(editList, trans );
}
```

If anyone has another explanation about why the first function works fine but the second one throws an exception, it would be very apreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks quite peculiar indeed. But additionally I want you to consider one more issue - specifically: what happens in your first example if `await insertTask` errors? `updateTask` runs unobserved, and this is generally bad news. Best case scenario - you miss out on handling its result (or failure) when it finishes. Worst case scenario - you immediately start running some other code (which is not supposed to run concurrently with `updateTask`), and create a hard-to-catch bug, or end up with a data corruption. Always use `Task.WhenAll` or a similar mechanism of observing multiple concurrent tasks.

Comment: Thanks Kirill for he comment! Updated the source using "await Task.WhenAll(tasks);"